# find in std::vector<std::pair>

Tags: c++, boost, std, c++98

I have a vector of pairs. The first in the pair is of type std::string and the second is of type Container.

What convenient functionality exists in std or boost so that I can return a Container given the string value as key?

**UPDATE**

It has been commented that I could use a std::map instead, but I actually need to preserve the order of my items, in the order that I push them to the vector.

Comment: In this case, why `std::vector` and not `std::map`?

Comment: `std::find_if` and a custom predicate (lambda in C++11)

Comment: @Andy Prowl I've marked my question as c++98

Comment: @meh I need to preserve the order of the items in the vector

Comment: @Baz: Sorry, I missed the tag. Well, the answer is the same, except for  the part within parentheses

Comment: Noting this and your other question, it probably would have been better if you asked a single question about a container that supported both lookup by string key and by insertion order. Each half of that question is easy to answer in isolation (use map/use vector) but the combination makes it a challenge.

Comment: Why not use a `std::map<std::string,std::vector<Container>>`?

Answer (score 9):

A possible solution:

```
struct comp
{
    comp(std::string const& s) : _s(s) { }

    bool operator () (std::pair<std::string, Container> const& p)
    {
        return (p.first == _s);
    }

    std::string _s;
};

// ...

typedef std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Container> > my_vector;
my_vector v;

// ...

my_vector::iterator i = std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), comp("World"));
if (i != v.end())
{
    Container& c = i->second;
}

// ...
```

Here is a complete example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

struct Container
{
    Container(int c) : _c(c) { }
    int _c;
};

struct comp
{
    comp(std::string const& s) : _s(s) { }

    bool operator () (std::pair<std::string, Container> const& p)
    {
        return (p.first == _s);
    }

    std::string _s;
};

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    typedef std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Container> > my_vector;
    my_vector v;
    v.push_back(std::make_pair("Hello", Container(42)));
    v.push_back(std::make_pair("World", Container(1729)));
    my_vector::iterator i = std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), comp("World"));
    if (i != v.end())
    {
        Container& c = i->second;
        std::cout << c._c; // <== Prints 1729
    }
}
```

And here is a [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/yJL1f$16).

Comment: it would appear that the link to the live example is broken

Answer (score 1):

Using [Boost.Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/non_mutating/find_if.html) and [Boost.Bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/bind/bind.html#with_function_objects), you can do this:

```
struct predicate
{
    template<class Key, class Pair>
    bool operator()(const Key& k, const Pair& p) const
    {
        return p.first == k;
    }
};

// Your vector of pairs
std::vector<std::pair<std:string, Container> v = ...;
// The key you would like to search for
std::string key = ...;
Container& c = boost::find_if(v, boost::bind(predicate(), key, _1))->second;
```

Comment: In that case, it would be possible to replace `boost::bind` with `std::bind1st` and get rid of boost this way.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution: use `std::copy` and `std::inserter`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <utility> // pair
#include <vector>

void function()
{
    typedef int Data;
    typedef std::pair< std::string, Data > String_Data_Pair;
    typedef std::vector< String_Data_Pair > String_Data_Pair_Sequence;
    typedef std::map< std::string, Data > String_To_Data_Map;

    String_Data_Pair_Sequence string_data_pairs;

    /* fill 'string_data_pairs' here */

    String_To_Data_Map string_to_data_map;

    std::copy( string_data_pairs.begin(),
               string_data_pairs.end(),
               std::inserter( string_to_data_map,
                              string_to_data_map.begin() /* superfluous, but required */ ) );
}
```

Comment: Can't you just replace the copy with `String_To_Data_Map string_to_data_map(string_data_pairs.begin(), string_data_pairs.end());`?

Comment: Yes... yes you can.  I sometimes forget about the range-based constructors.

Answer (score 0):

```
class SomeClass{
   int num;
public:
   SomeClass();
   void setNumber(int n) const { num = n;}
};

vector<pair<SomeClass,string> > vectr;

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < vectr.size(); i++)
   if(vectr[i].second == "key")
       vectr[i].first.setNumber(50);
```

Worked for me!